# What is the meaning of the Hex Maniac 'Ghost' girl in the unnamed Lumoise City building?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

After I earned eight badges I went to check if there is something interesting in all the  buildings in Lumiose City. In one of the buildings on the Northern Boulevard (without a name), I went to the 2nd floor, and something really creepy happened.

The music stopped. The screen [faded a few times.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvJ8u.png) I was unable to move or do any actions. Then a Hex Maniac girl [floated around me in absolute silence.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjSUS.png) She floated away at the end of scene, saying only...

[image: No, you're not the one...]

I went around searching for the girl or any clue. I found nothing. It was a regular cubicle-office floor without people. 1st and 3rd floors have people doing their own stuff.

*Is this some kind of developer joke, easter egg connected with Pokemon creepypasta, or is it something else?*

[Album of images of the above-mentioned events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jx9hA.jpg). (Original Source: [Reddit /r/pokemon post](http://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/1ox7mi/gamefreak_scared_me_once_again/), "GameFreak scared me once again...")

I experienced this. Check it out if you dare :)

Comment: I heard it's related to a future event featuring Hoopa.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it has something to do with either Rotom or Cresselia in X/Y (I'm playing X and I got the eerie-hex-maniac-girl-ghost too). The Strange House (at the base of Reversal Mountain) in Black2/White2 is where you get the Lunar Wing to catch Cresselia on Marvelous Bridge (also haunted), and in Diamond/Pearl, Rotom can be found in the haunted Old Chateau in Eterna Forest. 
I could be wrong of course, it's just a theory. There's still LOADS of stuff we don't know about X/Y yet. It might even have something to do with Darkrai, for all I know. Sorry I couldn't be of much help.

Answer (score 0):

Though I personally have not tried this, a [forum post on Marriland](http://www.marriland.com/forums/pokemon-6th-generation/pokemon-x-y/459193-pokemon-x-and-y-mysteries) (and brief [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=lumiose%20rotom%20rare%20candy&aq=f&oq=lumiose%20ro&aqs=chrome.0.59j57j0l2j60.2054j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)) says that you can

> Bring Rotom to the floor on Tuesdays to obtain Rare Candy.

Other sources (none that are particularly reliable, note) say that it has to be at 9pm.

Answer (score -3):

[There is Youtube video about that now with all clues.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCW-cCdQ61c)

Comment: Please don't just link to youtube for answers.  Summarize the information here, so that if the video ever goes down, your answer is still good.

Comment: Or those of us who can't watch Youtube can tell what its about.